# Database settings security

Tags: php, mysql, security, variables

I've got a file on my site called dbSettings.php with the lines:

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $dbName = "database";
    $user = "user";
    $pwd = "pass";
    $db = new mysqli($host, $user, $pwd, $dbName);
?>
```

I get this page into my main page with the require_once() function. Is there ANY way for someone who's reaching this page through the server(my domain) to get a hold of the values stored in these variables? Is this a secure way to keep the database settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common way to keep database credentials in php applications. Generally a config file would keep those settings some good practices are

- Proper file permissions to the file such as
  `chmod the file 640 instead of 600. Keep file ownership to your user and change group to webserver. This way, the webserver can only read and not modify it`
- Move file out of webroot so its not accessible directly by others
- Only give needed database privileges to that database user
  `If user just needs to access one database only give privileges for that database and data not give Structure or Administration related privileges if not needed`
- If possible protect with
  `.htaccess

  <files dbSettings.php>
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
  </files>`

Comment: You mean give permission to the user the web server is run as

Comment: that would be chmod to 600 and make webserver owner but I believe chmod to 640 keep file owner separate and giving webserver as group is better because in case of a compromise they can only be read

Comment: I'm not talking about the file mode, I'm talking about the file owner. It's the web server that needs to be able to access the credentials, not the database user. Hoperfully these are not the same user.

Answer (score 2):

If your webserver is configured properly, web clients should not be able to view the settings. When a `.php` file is accessed through the webserver, it executes the script, and returns what it prints to the client. The source code of the script is not sent to the client.

You can make things more secure by putting files like this outside your webroot. Then clients can't even address them, they can only be accessed by being `require`d from another script.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know of PHP security, there are a couple ways for this information to leak:

1. If dbSettings.php can be somehow loaded by a client, without the server processing the page.  This would obviously give out the details, since they can just look at the file.  Generally speaking, if you server is correctly configured, and and you have no backup files created, this shouldn't be an issue.
2. If dbSettings.php is loaded by the client, you want to make sure no errors could leak the information (so for instance the mysqli creation can't fail and leak the information).  Since your app isn't initialized, it is possible for errors you regularly mask to appear.

As for securely storing the information, I don't believe there is a much better solution then to do as Barmar suggests, and put the configuration files somewhere the web server doesn't actually serve files.  PHP can still generally access these files, but the web server won't give them out to clients.  Depending upon your hosts, this may or may not be possible.

Comment: It's a rare case that you *wouldn't* be able to write somewhere outside your web root, even on a shared server.

Comment: @Mike, True, but I don't trust what is available on shared hosting until I've seen it with my own eyes.  Of course, on your own stuff, it is whatever you've configured.  Also, if you're host is really strict they may not let you access such files.  Also (hopefully) a rare case.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by not trusting until you've seen it with your own eyes. No matter what shared hosting you're on, you're still at the mercy of the server admin. Anyone who has root access can access your files no matter where or how they are stored.

Comment: @Mike, I meant I wouldn't trust what a shared hosting provider gives me until I've actually used there service and seen what they do.  Since whether or not you have storage space outside your web root is not directly advertised, I wouldn't trust the hosting provider to give it to me.  Or that they haven't locked down PHP is some ridiculous fashion.  Or some other silliness.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your dbSettings.php is not accessible through URL, so php must be able to read this file, but this file should not be accessble by typing it's address in the browser (by guessing, luck, etc). But if you have properly configured www server you should be fine because php will be processed and blank page will be returned to user.

Only if you misconfigure your web server so it will not process php pages but return them to the user - the file will accessible by others to download. So again your settings must not be accessible from outside.

Besides that You should never have echo, dump, etc those values from your php code on production server and you should also catch any errors from mysql driver so they will not be printed out to the user on production server.

Answer (score 0):

The most important security measure, as outlined by previous answers, is proper webserver configuration.

As you are creating a configuration file that should never be directly accessed, you can safely place it outside the server root, or in a directory for which the server is configured to not serve files. As long as the file has proper permissions, you can `include()` it without the webserver's help.

If for what ever reason you choose to stick with having the configuration file in an accessible location, you can use a `define()` trick to prevent unauthorised execution. This is done by defining a constant in the file to include the config file, prior to the actual `include()`, then checking for the existence of the constant in the config file itself.

example.php:

```
<?php
  define ('my_const', 1);
  include ('config.php');

  echo $super_secret_data;
?>
```

config.php:

```
<?php
  if (!defined ('my_const'))
    die ();

  $super_secret_data = 42;
?>
```

Of course, the only security benefit here is that executable code will not run without the constant if the page is accessed directly, and that its data will not be accessible by files that do not define the const (which is pretty bad security through obscurity, as you can probably still call `getfilecontents()` on the file).